# Is there any way to check accessibility IDs existence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uikit

I need to be sure that all textfields, buttons and other controls in iOS app have accessibility identifiers

How it can be done? Swiftlint? CI/CD check? Custom Build Phase?

Comment: Could you explain more about the same, What exactly you are going for?

Comment: It will be very helpful for UI testing

Answer (score 1):

As UIButton and UITextField are UIControls also..
extend UIControl as Category and hook up into initWithFrame (if used everywhere), check the ID and print it.

```
@interface UIControl (AccessibilityIDDebugging)
@end

@implementation UIControl (AccessibilityIDDebugging)
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (!(self=[super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;
    if (self.accessibilityIdentifier==NULL) 
        NSLog(@"accessibilityId (%@:%p) = %@", self.class, self, self.accessibilityIdentifier);
    return self;
}
@end
```

alternative hook up into another method that is invoked on each UI element when loading your views because you could have set accessibilityIdentifier programatically and much later than initiation.

And total overlooked, you could use the find and replace tool of Xcode.